# How to disable toolbar in docusign in-person view?

Tags: docusignapi

I have configured docusign with my developer account. I have configured a placeholder for signer to sign at the bottom of the document. And the same is visible in the recipient view in template edit mode. But when I am trying to access the document via in-person view for signing, I am able to see the menu in left panel, from where the signer will be able to sign wherever they want. The placeholder that I set earlier is no-where to be seen.

What could be the reason?

**EDIT 1**

Adding code used for creating envelope:

```
TemplateRole signer = new TemplateRole();
signer.setEmail("abc@gmail.com");
signer.setName("John Doe");
signer.setRoleName("Contractor");

EnvelopeDefinition envelope = new EnvelopeDefinition();
signer.setClientUserId("actual uuid");

envelope.setTemplateId("actual template id");
envelope.setTemplateRoles(Collections.singletonList(signer));
envelope.setStatus("sent");

return envelope;
```

**EDIT 2**

Added picture of template setup from docusign.
[image]

[image: picture for reference]

**EDIT 3**

Based on one answer, modified role name in code to Contractor, so that role name in template and in code are same. No I am getting this error:

```
For In Person Signer type, the Recipient Signer Name cannot be blank.
```

Clearly I am supplying name in code.

Comment: This means your tags are not being assigned correctly. Can you share an API log or code block that shows how you are setting up your envelope definition (with any PII removed)?

Comment: @Drew I have edited the question with code, can you check now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your template has "Contractor" as the role name but in your code
the role name is "signer".

It must match the template for the tabs to appear.

Also add this:

```
signer.setInPersonSignerName("Inbar Gazit");
```

Comment: I have placed signature placeholder in template for sure. I have also added code for making envelope in the question.

Comment: Changed both to same, now it gives this error "For In Person Signer type, the Recipient Signer Name cannot be blank."

Comment: making progress here, let me update the answer for you yet again,...